# No pages were found in your facebook account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I connected a desktop software to Facebook using API. I have created an app to git an app id and a secret key.

The desktop software has successfully connected to my Facebook account. However, it gives me the following error in a pop-up message box:

> No pages were found in your Facebook account.
>
> Please add some pages to your Facebook account, or authenticate for a user id that has pages.

Here is what the pop-up looks like:

[image: Pop-up error]

However I have a Facebook page in that personal account. Why is the API unable to detect that page?

Comment: Did it ask you for permission to access your pages in the FB login dialog …?

Comment: No. It got connected to my personal fb account first, then started displaying this error dialogue

Comment: Apps can only ask “normal” users for the necessary permission, after the app has been reviewed and approved by Facebook. You need to use an account that has a role in your app (admin/developer/tester), if your app is not reviewed and approved yet.